# Round brackets not showing up correctly in RightToLeft flow direction in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, localization, globalization, right-to-left

Flow direction in my WPF window is set to RightToLeft like so:

```
<TextBlock FlowDirection="RightToLeft" x:Name="test">
```

In code if I do `test.Text = "(2/3)";` I see

> (2/3)

But if I do `test.Text = "asdf (2/3)";` I see

> (asdf (2/3

What's going on here? Why is it that starting the text with a string changes the positioning of the brackets?

Comment: If you think that this is a BUG, you could submit it to  http://connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure, but another more complex workaround is:

> Friday, February 12, 2010 5:10 PM
> Ben Ronco - MSFT
>
> Unfortunately this is a bug that we
> have recently discovered.  You may be
> able to work around this issue by
> puttting some "invisible" non
> punctuation text at the end of your
> content like this:

```
{example modified}

<TextBlock FlowDirection="RightToLeft" x:Name="test">                    
    <Run>Label1 (cms)</Run>
    <Run FontSize=".01">i</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Source:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3a723659-2bac-4d0c-80d8-09ba38e6cec1

Answer (score 1):

When you have punctuation text at the end of the content try to use:

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
```

instead of:

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```

From: Vladvaly
October 20, 2010 6:39 AM
Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3a723659-2bac-4d0c-80d8-09ba38e6cec1

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with related to StackPanel and Buttons.

Previous (not working way):
[NotWorkingScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hDUm.png)

Previous code:

```
<StackPanel Margin="2"
        FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button x:Name="buttonSaveFlipchart"
        Width="100"
        Margin="2"
        Click="buttonSaveFlipchart_Click"
        Content="{Binding Path=ButtonContentSave}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabledSaveFlipchart}" />
<Button x:Name="buttonEditFlipchart"
        Margin="2"
        Click="buttonEditFlipchart_Click"
        Content="Muokkaa"
        IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabledEditFlipchart}" />
```

New (working way):
[WorkingScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urx30.png)

New code:

```
<StackPanel Margin="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button x:Name="buttonEditFlipchart"
        Margin="2"
        Click="buttonEditFlipchart_Click"
        Content="Muokkaa"
        IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabledEditFlipchart}" />
<Button x:Name="buttonSaveFlipchart"
        Width="100"
        Margin="2"
        Click="buttonSaveFlipchart_Click"
        Content="{Binding Path=ButtonContentSave}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabledSaveFlipchart}" />
```

**So import were the changing of attribute FlowDirection to HorizontalAlignment.**